# Complicated Loop with python and selenium for variables

Tags: python, selenium

i struggle with a loop for my projekt:
For example:

```
user = "1" , "2", ...

Link = www.test.com/
```

what can i do that it goes to

```
www.test.com/1
does something

www.test.com/2
does the same thing

...
```

so it does the same thing for every user

Comment: You should share more details along with code you've already tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function and apply it to list of users:

```
def perform_for_each_user(user_list, link):
    for user in user_list:
        user_link = link + user
        print(user_link)
        # do something with user_link

users = "1" , "2", "3"

perform_for_each_user(users, "www.test.com/")
```